Android Studio putting cache in wrong project folder
I have two projects in Android Studio: ProjectA, ProjectB
When I Clean and Build ProjectB, it was putting the cache files into:
/ProjectA/android/
rather than
/ProjectB/android/
I deleted the .idea and cache folders from both projects, Invalidated Cache, and Restart and now I'm getting an error:
/ProjectA/android/caches/8.10.2/groovy-dsl/ec1db08b50cf37b98a3641d74bdbd3bc/metadata.bin (No such file or directory)
I don't know how to get it to create the caches in the correct project directory's android folder.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Android Studio Ladybug 2024.2.1 Patch 2
Android Gradle Plugin 8.7.2
Gradle Version 8.10.2

